# Magento 2.2.1 : Product disappeared every time after edit

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, category-products, magento-2.2.1

Each time when I modify a product (image or quantity) it disappears from the site.

Then it comes back after the site is re-indexed.

Any ideas how can I stop this from happening?

I have also tried following solution but its not working.

[Magento2 - Products suddenly disappeared on frontend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88081/magento2-products-suddenly-disappeared-on-frontend/92155)

Comment: Have you set cron.?

Comment: Yes, and cron is already working fine

Comment: there are disappear all products or just few specifics? Can You check you can reproduce issue with product assign to 1 category and with product assign to 2 and more categories? Anyway indexing are set on update on save or update on scheduler?

Comment: not all product but specific product. the disappeared product which I have edited other products are showing fine.

Comment: Anyway indexing are set on update on save or update on scheduler?
>> I have tried with both options but same result.